# Set alarm in same file

Tags: android, alarmmanager

For some reason I would like to have an AlarmManager to call a broadcast receiver in the same code file so I did something like this:

```
AlarmManager oAlarmManager;
PendingIntent oPendingIntentAlarm;

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, clsMyReceiver.class);   
oPendingIntentAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
oAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
oAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, oPendingIntentAlarm); //Execute in 5 seconds for testing
```

Then, in this same file I have:

```
public class clsMyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{         
   @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {  //This is never reached
   }
}
```

I have declared it in the Manifest like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".clsMyReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>
```

But as I said, the OnReceive in the broadcast is never triggered. Any suggestion?

Comment: is this just wrong copied into here: oPendingIntentAlarma ? You have only oPendingIntentAlarm <--with "a" at the end

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong copied.

Comment: Are clsMyReceiver and the activity from which you set the alarm in same package?

Comment: Well, they are in the same java file, so same package too

Comment: what if you delete the process=":remote", anyway, usually You don´t Need to deal with two separated processes on most apps

Comment: Oh ok, I had no idea what was that for. I removed but same result.

Comment: short, it is to run the Receiver in a different process, but this is not important here. So, at some applications I had a similar Problem and I defined the Receiver with the complete package Name, maybe it helps. try it..